# Air Serbia denied return flight after not taking outbound one

Tags: refunds, missed-flights

I booked a flight from Copenhagen to Athens with Air Serbia. Due to the death of a relative, I had to reschedule my first flight to an earlier flight.

Air Serbia states that:

> Please be advised that in the event you do not show up for any flight without advising Air Serbia in advance, Air Serbia may cancel your return or onward reservations.

I tried to contact them thrice but their call centre didn't answer my calls. Also, they didn't inform me of the cancellation of my return flight and I learned about it one day before my flight when I tried to check in. Can anyone inform me if I am entitled to any form of refund?

Comment: It's usual practice for (almost) all airlines that return flight is cancelled if the passenger didn't take the outbound flight. Buying the tickets you agreed with these terms.

Comment: How did you reschedule your first flight? Did you rebook your initial ticket with Air Serbia?

Comment: As explained in the answers, you are probably not _entitled_ to a refund. However, that does not mean that they won't give you a refund if you ask them nicely and explain your situation. Second, you should check if any travel or credit card insurance you have might cover this case.

Answer (score 15):

The use of your ticket is covered by the "[Contract of Carriage](https://www.airserbia.com/en/conditions-of-carriage)" of the airline.

Air Serbia, like most airlines, including a condition in it's contract of carriage as follows :

> 3.3 COUPON SEQUENCE AND USE
>
> The Ticket you have purchased is valid only for the transportation as
>   shown on the Ticket, from the place of departure via any Agreed
>   Stopping Places to the final destination. The fare you have paid is
>   based upon Air Serbia Tariff and is for the transportation as shown on
>   the Ticket. It forms an essential part of Air Serbia contract with
>   you. **The Ticket will not be honoured and will lose its validity if all
>   the Coupons are not used in the sequence provided in the Ticket.**

Given that you failed to use the first "Coupon" (ie, the outbound flight), any subsequent flights on the same ticket are also invalid.

Whether you are due a refund will depend on the exact ticket, but in most cases a refund would only be possible if you notified the airline that you were not planning to make the initial flight BEFORE the time that flight was due to depart.  For most tickets, once that flight departs without you, then your entire ticket would have no value.

The only people who can really tell you if a refund is due is the airline themselves (or possibly the travel agent if it was booked via one), but as I said above, it's very likely that nothing is due.

Comment: OP can get airport taxes back

Comment: @Crazydre That would depend on the airlines policies and (as already mentioned) potentially the ticket purchased.  Many will NOT give a refund of taxes in a situations like this.

Comment: I thought they were obliged to for any flight a passenger did not go on (possibly subject to a fee of course such as Ryanair)

Comment: "Please be advised that In the event you do not show up for any flight without advising Air Serbia in advance, Air Serbia may cancel your return or onward reservations." What if I tried to inform them that i didnt show up and their call center didnt answer my calls?

Answer (score 3):

The rule is that if you fail to travel any segment of your trip, the rest of the trip auto-cancels.  That applies on most scheduled transport including trains.  This is to combat "hidden city ticketing": often,  for marketing or subsidy reasons, Bumblebutt-SFO-JFK is cheaper than SFO-JFK, or a round trip is cheaper than a one-way.

If you didn't know about this rule and just booked some random one-way, that's on you.  Because it's your job to know that rule.  That is why it is in disclosures they give you.

However (I'm taking your word here) you **rescheduled**.  That means you contacted the carrier, told them of your change of plans, and had them change your ticket for the earlier departure.   In that case, yes, they screwed up and it's on them.

Comment: @Doc Finnair also won't modify itineraries. IT says on their policy page the returns may be cancelled unless they're notified, but when notifying them, they'll just reply that  you must take the correct sequence or subsequent flights WILL be cancelled

Comment: @Crazydre The answer was modified after my comment, so my comment doesn't make much sense now.

Comment: @Doc yeah sorry, I fixed it on your suggestion and got pulled off on a task before I could say anything.

Comment: Right, this all depends on what the OP means by “I had to reschedule my first flight”.